# Asynchronous request not working after separating data retrieval code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying to display some results after querying a webapi as below -

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        string _address = "someurl";
        string results = null;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new OAuthMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));
        HttpResponseMessage responseTask = await client.GetAsync(_address);

        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            results = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        ResultModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(results);

        return View(model);
    }
```

This code works fine and I am able to read the results from "someurl" url. Now, when I refator the code as below (by moving the async data retrieval to another function), it stops working. It forever takes to query and does not return any result. Is this because of some deadlock or am I not using async correctly.

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
        string _address = "someurl";
        Task<string> results = HttpClientService.HttpClientService.GetRequest(_address);

        IEnumerable<ResultModel> model  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultModel>>(results.Result);

        return View(model);
}

public static class HttpClientService
{
    public static async Task<string> GetRequest(string Url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new OAuthMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));
        HttpResponseMessage responseTask = await client.GetAsync(Url);

        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        else
        {
            return "Sorry buddy, cannot retrieve the requested data!";
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. I am new to Async implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await the GetRequest method. Otherwise you are defeating the purpose of async processing which is to release the thread so it can do other work. In this case you are still blocking the thread when you ask for a result via results.Result.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
        string _address = "someurl";
        string results = await HttpClientService.HttpClientService.GetRequest(_address);

        IEnumerable<ResultModel> model  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultModel>>(results);

        return View(model);
}
```

Frankly I am not sure why your code is not returning but even if it was working correctly it would be pointless to do async requests in this way.

Comment: I changed as below - 
return type as -- async Task<ActionResult> 
calling method as -- string results = await HttpClientService.HttpClientService.GetRequest(_address);

This works fine. I would like to know what do you mean by "even if it was working correctly it would be pointless to do async requests in this way". Please let me know what is your thinking behind this?

Comment: The point of using async in Web applications (I assume this is a web application) is to free the executing thread to do other things while you are waiting for the result of an async operation. When you request .Result of async operation the thread blocks (instead of doing other things) until the async operation is complete. You are basically doing things synchronously in a more complex way.

Comment: I got your point, but my concern is that when I am already returning as - return await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); , why do I have to await again at the calling statement? Is it really wrong to write async in this way? I have to put it in a separate method as I am calling it from couple of different places. Is there any better way to achieve this? Sorry I am new to async, but I need to understand this bit.

Comment: What they say about async is that when you do async it is async all the way down. This means that the async operation (and the corresponding awaiting) goes through all the layers. This is true for web applications and for desktop applications because the thread you want to let go is in the top layer.

In your case a request gets a thread asks for something to happen asynchronously and continues on until it hits .Result when it waits for the result. What you want to happen is that the thread stops immediately and stores a Task somewhere and continues when the task is done.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. So, I am to assign the result from function call in a Task<string> object and continue working and then await that object to retrive the value. Thanks a lot Stilgar.

Comment: No, you are supposed to await the result of the method. await extracts the result from the tasks. You are supposed to write code as if it was synchronous code but your methods return Task<Something> instead of Something and when you call them you call them with await. Follow this rule and you will not get it wrong.

Of course I encourage you to go and read how things work internally but the above is the rule of thumb. Just pretend the code is synchronous and add await where the method returns a Task and make your methods return a Task and be async if they contain calls to other async methods.

Comment: In below, I can "do other tasks while the caller thread waits for the result and can then retrieve it by using await later below. Isn't this why we'll use asynchronous requests? Let me know if I am thinking this in a wrong way. Please tell me how would you write this?

public ActionResult Get()
{
        string _address = "someurl";
        Task<string> results = HttpClientService.HttpClientService.GetRequest(_address);

// do other tasks 

        IEnumerable<ResultModel> model  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultModel>>(await results);

        return View(model);
}

Comment: You are correct you can do other Tasks in the meantime and in general it is a good thing. However more often than not you can't do other (significant) tasks until the operation is complete because the code after it depends on the result of the operation. The thing is that in this case there is still benefit to use async/await because this means better scalability. 1 thread can serve multiple users if it is not tied up waiting for a database operation or something. If you show what other tasks you want to execute I can tell you the appropriate way to do it with async/await.

Comment: I need to be able to make multiple web service calls in parallel like above (they might each take more than couple of minutes to complete) to get data and also run them asynchronously (let's say for logging the downloaded data).

Comment: Oh I see. Then you can make the requests store them as tasks (let's say in a List<Task<result>>) and then when you have fired all the requests do await Task.WhenAll(theListOfTasks). You will combine both approaches. Of course if that is your main goal you may not bother with async/await at all and let the thread block.

Comment: Got it. Will try it for my application. Thanks a lot again for explaining so clearly.